# Как возвращать несколько объектов в шаблон из класса-представлений от Джанго?

Tags: django

```
class Example(ListView):
    model=Example
    template_name = "example.html"
    context_object_name = "example"
```

Как можно передать в шаблон несколько объектов? Может есть какие то спец.атрибуты от самого Джанго? Или это надо самому в функции модели обернуть или в представлениях.

Comment: Вы уже передаете все объекты модели `Example`. Если нужна какая-то фильтрация, то переопределите метод `get_queryset()`.

Comment: Прошу прощения я имел ввиду  другие модели. Как передать объект других моделей. Чтобы в шаблоне можно было использовать к примеру модель A и модель B

Comment: Переопределить `get_context_data`. http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.list/ListView/#get_context_data

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло.